# How to access the folder of a project directly in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have tried as per in the link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html

I have got the project id. The problem is I am not sure how to give file path.
when i give

> http://{domain}/api/v3/projects/{id}/repository/files

, getting the error as

```
{
    "message": "400 (Bad request) \"file_path\" not given"
}
```

When I give

> http://{domain}/api/v3/projects/{id}/repository/files/src/main/resources/test.xml

, then getting

> 404

error.
My gitlab struture is

> http://{domain}/namespace/{test-component}/src/main/resources/test.xml

. what is the correct way to give folder struture? where can i get the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation try `http://{domain}/api/v3/projects/{id}/repository/files/src/main/resources? file_path=test.xml&ref=master`